# Sharing JS files across application

Tags: javascript

We're developing a mobile application and we're trying to figure out the best approach to share javascript functions across the application.

At the moment we have individual files that simply have:

```
var LIB = {
    URL: "http://localhost/service",
    connect: function() {
       // connect to server
      $.ajax({ url: this.URL }); // etc etc

      // call a private function?
      this._somethingElse();
    },
    _somethingElse: function() {
      // do something else
    }
};
```

Then we simply call things like:

`LIB.connect();` or `LIB.disconnect();`

across any file.

This also gives us access to `LIB.URL` as well.

My question is whether this approach is the best?

I've seen people use the following approach as well, but to what benefit?

```
var LIB = function () {
    this.URL = "http://localhost/service";
    this.connect = function () {
      var myself = this;
      // connect to server
      $.ajax({ url: this.URL }); // etc etc

      // call a private function?
      myself._somethingElse(); // best way to invoke a private function?
    };
    this._somethingElse = function () {
      // do something else
    };
};
```

This requires the following:

`var lib = new LIB();`

`lib.connect();`

**EDIT:**

I've also seen the following:

```
window.lib = (function () {
    function Library () {
    }

    var lib = {
        connect: function () {
          // connect to server
        }   
    };

    return lib;
}());
```

I'm slightly confused with all these options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different approaches to structuring JavaScript code for re-usability. You can research these and decide which is best. Me personally, I have used the second approach that you've outlined. However, I separate my code into sections and actually adhere to an MVVM structure. So for instance, I have a name space called models and view models. Each of my js files begins with:

`window.[APP NAME].Models.[CLASS/MODULE NAME] or window.[APP NAME].Models.[CLASS/MODULE NAME]`

So, let's say I have a namespace called mynamespace and I have a module/class called myclass. My js file would begin with:

```
window.MYNAMESPACE = window.MYNAMESPACE || {};
window.MYNAMESPACE.ViewModels = window.MYNAMESPACE.ViewModels || {};

window.MYNAMESPACE.ViewModels.MyClass = function () {
    // a public function
    this.func1 = function () {
    };

    // a private function
    function func2() {
    }
};
```

I would then consume that class by calling:

```
var myClassModel = new window.MYNAMESPACE.ViewModels.MyClass();
myClassModel.func1();
```

This gives you some nice encapsulation of your code. Some of the other patterns you can research/google are: Prototype Pattern, Module Pattern, Revealing Module Pattern, and the Revealing Prototype Pattern.

I hope that helps but if you have any questions on what I've just said, feel free to comment on this post.

Comment: What if I need to access a property of another `ViewModel.MyClass()` inside an existing `ViewModel.MyClass()`?

Comment: ...or a property within a private function?

Comment: Reference each class's js file and then instantiate it with a single line in your site's main script. For example, when I'm using an MVVM pattern, I have a js file that is my view model. It contains all the code that glues the model to the view. The view is the html page and the models (or services if you prefer to think of it like that) contain whatever reusable code you have. The view model file can contain the document.ready function outside of the viewmodel closure. You can "new up" models inside or outside the viewmodel closure (var x = new MyClass(); x.func1();).

Comment: Would you mind creating a simple jsfiddle example of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

It just depends on which you like better. I (on a personal level) prefer the former, but to each his own. The latter does have the disadvantage of requiring to either remember to declare the `new` before using it, or having to keep track of a already created one.

Additionally, on a technical level the first one should get slightly (as in, barely noticeable) performance, as you don't have to compute a new function.

**Edit** Yes, the first way is [definitely the fastest](http://jsperf.com/existing-or-new-object-for-libs).

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend going with a module system. Until ES6 comes along (http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:modules), you will have to use a 3rd party library in order to do this.

- Each object/class/util/etc is a module.
- A module exports a public api, whereas consuming modules import other modules by declaring their dependencies.
- Two "standards" that exist: AMD and CommonJS. In the browser, a library like RequireJS, which uses the AMD standard, is very popular. I recommend checking out their site first: http://requirejs.org/ and see their examples.

The main advantage here is that you only expose the public api, which allows you to create a sandbox of your functionality. It's also more explicit as it's really easy to see what your module depends on, instead of relying on global objects.